# Does Craft ActiveRecord require any special table column (dateUpdated, dateCreated,...)?

Tags: plugin-development, database

I have a custom data table PA in the Craft database. I create a craft\db\ActiveRecord model and I want load() and save() data to it. The result will be custom GridView table with CRUD in front end combined with cms pages.

When I call $model->save() it throws Exception:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dateUpdated' in 'field list'

The SQL being executed was: UPDATE `PA` SET `background`='#ffff00', `dateUpdated`='2018-10-03 11:50:26' 
WHERE `idPA`=17
Error Info: Array
(
[0] => 42S22
[1] => 1054
[2] => Unknown column 'dateUpdated' in 'field list'
)

Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dateUpdated' in 'field list'
```

What is the difference between craft\db\ActiveRecord and yii\db\ActiveRecord? Is there any recommendation how to use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between Craft and Yii active records are the columns `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated` and `uid` if you have these columns you should extend Crafts `ActiveRecord` since it's `save` function adds compability to those columns otherwise  just use Yii2 `ActiveRecord`

Comment: The problem still consist if use yii\db\ActiveRecord; is extended

Comment: It became a little bit more difficult. It's easier to either include those columns or not use ActiveRecords. Otherwise you would need to inject a different `yii/db/Command` class to the existing `yii/db/Schema`/`yii/db/Connection` in order to use different `Command` class for your ActiveRecord.